# F.lux settings?

Tags: windows-7, readability, f.lux

How can I get into the F.lux settings? I can just right-click the taskbar icon, but can only change location.

How can I access the other settings?

I'm on Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The menu plays up for me on my Windows 7 32 bit machine too so I'm guessing it must be a bug.

*Left-clicking* should bring up the **Change Lighting** option.

Comment: Interesting, right-clicking on the icon brings up the menu & the settings for me (Win 7x64 - ultimate). ('m out of votes, will vote when they get replenished). Ed: nope, it disappears. Left-clicking will bring up th setting

Comment: For me left-clicking does not bring up settings.

Comment: Aha, I just had to exit f.lux and restart it again, now i get settings.